# Search exists api not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, exists

Following the indications on the [Elasticsearch documentation here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-exists.html):  ,I am trying to determine if a query yields results in the most efficient manner, by using _search/exists.

When I use _search, I get a valid result, but _search/exists with the same query, returns a "No handler found" error.

Here are some CURLs to show the issue:

mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test-plugin-search/_mapping/testType" -d '{
  "testType": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": false
      },
      "b": {
        "type": "double",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": false
      },
      "c": {
        "type": "date",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": false
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Search:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test-plugin-search/testType/_search/" -d'     
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}'
```

Search result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-plugin-search",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "2K63Sp2LRm2OlaffuvMp4Q",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "a": "A",
          "b": 1.23,
          "c": "2014-12-26"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now search + exists:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test-plugin-search/testType/_search/exists" -d'     
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": { }
    }
}'
```

Result:

```
No handler found for uri [/test-plugin-search/testType/_search/exists] and method [GET]
```

I don't think that the documentation is wrong, so I am necessarily making a mistake, but I can't find it. Can someone please help out?

Comment: Did you try with -XPOST instead of -XGET?

Comment: Yes, I tried with both POST and GET.

Comment: What version of ES are you running?  _search/exists was added in 1.4

Comment: Hi Olly! You might want to Post this as the answer. The qbox cluster was running 1.3.1